# Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I have this query:

```
UPDATE student_info 
    set grade = (SELECT tempTable.grade 
                     FROM tempTable
                     WHERE student_info.s_id = (SELECT s_id FROM tempTable))
```

I've also tried the suggested solution here: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: the question is needed !

Comment: I have two tables, the student_info contains 3 rows (s_d, name, grade). Everything is filled except 'grade'. Using the tempTable table that has the same number of rows except it contains the grades, I want to transfer the grades from tempTable to student_info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you want:

```
UPDATE student_info 
  JOIN tempTable
    ON tempTable.s_id = student_info.s_id 
SET student_info.grade = tempTable.grade
```

Comment: I'll try that. Be back in a minute.

Comment: +1 Excellent guesswork, you are psychic! I just deleted a wrong answer before posting it, because I had misunderstood the problem ...

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery is returning more than one row, possibly because the JOIN is incorrect.  Try:

```
UPDATE student_info 
    SET grade = (SELECT grade 
         FROM tempTable
         WHERE s_id = student_info.s_id)
```

This of course assumes that `tempTable` only contains one record per `s_id`.  If there are more that one then you need to take the `TOP 1` ordered by some attribute (latest?  highest?)

Comment: This should work, too. MySQL has `LIMIT n` though, no `TOP n`.